# How to decorate a row in table using displaytag

Tags: java, struts2

I am using display tag to display values in a table. I want to color a specific row in the table based on the values in the column say 'Y' then color row with red color. How can i do this? I have been looking up the documentation for display tag which uses decorator class and `addRowClass()` method, but its too confusing. Is there a method to do this using JavaScript?

Comment: What language are you using, in what context, with what framework or SDK? Where's your code?

Comment: I am using Java with struts 2 framework

Answer (score 0):

I've been using the below javascript which I found [HERE](http://raibledesigns.com/rd/entry/displaytag_changing_a_row_s)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
    var table = document.getElementById("user");    
    var tbody = table.getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0];
    var rows = tbody.getElementsByTagName("tr");
    // add event handlers so rows light up and are clickable
    for (i=0; i < rows.length; i++) {
        var value = rows[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0].firstChild.nodeValue;
        if (value == 'mraible') {
            rows[i].style.backgroundColor = "red";
        }
    }
//-->
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set decorator="decorator" for your table and override addRowClass method.
`request.setAttribute("decorator", new org.displaytag.decorator.TableDecorator() {...});`

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a TableDecorator class, inside this class you have to create the method addRowClass(), that method return css class that you need, for example:

```
package com.example.decorator;
public class DisplayTagExampleDecorator extends TableDecorator {
@Override
 public String addRowClass() {   
     try { 
       return ((ObjectVO) getCurrentRowObject()).isHaveClass() ?
         * " bg-dark" : ""; 
      }
      catch(Exception e) 
      { 
       return ""; 
      } 
  }
}
```

In jsp file, you have to modify the decorator property, like this:

<display:table ... decorator="com.example.decorator.DisplayTagExampleDecorator">