# How to highlight a particular row of DisplayTag table?

Tags: jsp, displaytag

I want to highlight the DisplayTag's row which has value `'Total'` for this I was trying through javascript but I am uable to do that .Below is the snippet which I am using.Please guide.

Ref: [How to decorate a row in table using displaytag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1614283/how-to-decorate-a-row-in-table-using-displaytag)

I am getting the alert when there is Total in 2nd column but it does not get highlighted.

How to highlight a particular row which has value `Total` in 2nd column?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function onLoad(){
            var table = document.getElementById("data");    
            var tbody = table.getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0];
            var rows = tbody.getElementsByTagName("tr");

            for (i=0; i < rows.length; i++) {
                var value = rows[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[1].firstChild.nodeValue;

                if (value == 'Total') {
                    alert('true');
                    rows[i].style.backgroundColor = "red";

                            }
            }
        }

        </script>
    <body onload="onLoad();">
    <%AppUtil oAppUtil=new AppUtil();%>
    <jsp:useBean id="realTimeIssuance" scope="session" class="com.mindcraft.mis.tpd.actionform.afRealTimeIssuance"></jsp:useBean>

    <display:table name="realtimereportcol" export="true" pagesize="30" sort="list" id="data" requestURI="" class="tablelist" decorator="org.displaytag.decorator.TotalTableDecorator">


            <display:column title="SUB_CHANNEL" sortable="true" property="sub_channel"></display:column>
            <display:column title="AGENT_NAMES" sortable="true" property="agent_names"></display:column>
            <display:column title="FTD" sortable="true" property="ftd"  ></display:column>
            <display:column title="MTD" sortable="true" property="mtd"  ></display:column>
            <display:column title="QTD" sortable="true" property="qtd"  ></display:column>

    </display:table>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 3):

Use a TableDecorator and implement the addRowClass() method like below...

```
return ((ListObject)getCurrentRowObject()).getTotal() > 400 ? "highlight" : null;
```

You can then define the css for highlight in the CSS file.

Please refer their demo for more information http://demo.displaytag.org/displaytag-examples-1.1/example-rowclass.jsp

Answer (score 1):

You have to use DisplayTag decorators to manipulate data and html structure of the rendered table.

Create a simple Java class, inside your project package, which extends **TableDecorator** and overrides **addRowClass** method.

On a collection of class objects, the decorator class method **addRowClass** is called for each object in the collection.

```
public class TestTableDecorator extends TableDecorator {

    @Override
    public String addRowClass() {
        return ((AnObject) getCurrentRowObject()).getTotal() > your_threshold ? "css-class-1" : "css-class-2";
    }   

}
```

Now in your .jsp file declare your decorator inside the display:table using the attribute:

```
decorator="path.to.decorator.TestTableDecorator"
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, you can't set a background color on a `<tr>`. Instead, you must set it on each of its enclosed `<td>`.

I would define a CSS class like

```
tr.highlighted td {
    background-color: red;
}
```

and add the class `highlighted` to the appropriate `<tr>`.